# I2C Communication Issue with STM32 Nucleo Board: Unable to Find Slave Address

Tags: stm32, communication, i2c, nucleo

I am working with the STM32H743ZI2 NUCLEO BOARD. I have configured and programmed the board for general purposes, including GPIO, ADC, PWM, I2C, and SPI.
To validate the I2C part, I created a test board with two I2C devices on it. I confirmed address scanning, data transmission, and data reception with this test board.

Later, I attempted to communicate with another board containing a different I2C device using the programmed NUCLEO BOARD. However, when I executed the address scanning command, I couldn't find the slave address of the device, and I couldn't write data. I consulted a colleague, and they asked if I had connected pull-up resistors to the SDA-SCL pins. Upon reviewing the boards, I noticed that the test board, where I found the slave address, had pull-up resistors, while the other board did not.

Could this be the issue? If so, can I use pull-up resistors on the NUCLEO BOARD instead of the device where I cannot find the address?

Comment: Doesn't matter where the pull-up resistor is.

Comment: Do the boards share a common ground?

Comment: Yes, grounds are common

Comment: I2C bus need pull-up resistors, period. I don't think Nucleo board has any pull-up resistors for I2C bus, it is usually for the sensor board to add them.

Comment: I2C requires pull-ups. Typical values are 2.2k - 4.7k (so that it pulls ~1ma when the line is low; same value on both lines). Nucleo has built-in pull-ups, they're around 20k, which in practice means that it could still work, often does work, but it isn't guaranteed (and it obviously won't work if the internal pull-ups are not used). Can you detect your slave device using another I2C master? Also need to check electrical part more thoroughly. In idle state, clock and data lines are supposed to be high. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi Ilya, I can detect the slave (TPL0102 IC) using another master (ViperBoard). But ViperBoard has built-in pull-up resistors ( I checked). I also checked Nucleo-Board, it has not built-in pull up. Clock and data lines are low in idle state. 
I have tried adding a pull up resistor to nucleo via breadboard but it didn't work. NOTE: I removed the pull-up resistors from the test card with built-in pull-up resistors and I could not find the address with nucleo. But I can still find the address with viperboard